# Rails Assets Plugin Folders not being read in deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails-5

When I configured my app files I put my plugin folders under assets and in my config/application.rb file I added the following lines:

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Cnd
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.1
    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "images")
    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "bootstrap")
    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "rs-plugin-5")
    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "magnific-popup")
    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "owlcarousel2")
    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "morphext")
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
  end
end
```

Everything runs fine on my localhost when I deploy to an amazon ec2 I am getting the following error:

[image: error message]

I do not understand why it loads the files locally but when I deploy it is not. I am just deploying in development environment for right now. Not sure if this makes a difference but I am working on my production environment locally so I precompiled assets. The reason I deployed in development is because I just need to show the client quickly the progress.

Comment: have you precompiled you asset for production? with this command in production server RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

Comment: I did precompile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some work I figured it out. I had to use this line `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:clobber` to get rid of the precompile and then everything went back to normal. Now when I am ready for production I need to figure out how to precompile all of the assets including the plugins.